# new, delete ,malloc & free

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, free, new-operator

This question was asked to me in an interview:

> In  C++,
>
> 1. what if we allocate memory using `malloc` and use `delete` to free that allocated memory?
> 2. what if we allocate the memory using `new` and free it using `free`?
>
> What are the problems that we would face if the above things are used in the code?

My answer was there is no difference. Was I right in saying so?

Comment: This [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.3) answers these exact questions.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350819/c-free-store-vs-heap

Comment: I hope you answered right to the other questions

Comment: "there is no difference." -> That is technically correct, both points lead to undefined behavior, so there is no difference :)

Comment: As it was an interview question, I don't think they expected yes/no answer. You were expected to explain what malloc/free and new/delete do, how they differ, how they are used and **why** you should not mix them. This will show them that you know how C++ and C++ runtime works, how it relates to C standard library and that you can think about those issues. So, answering your question, with "answer [...] there is no difference" you failed. :-(

Comment: Read any [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-malloc-and-delete.html).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do so you will run into undefined behavior. Never try that. Although `new` might be implemented through `malloc()` and `delete` might be implemented through `free()` there's no guarantee that they are really implemented that way *and* also the user can overload `new` and `delete` at his discretion. You risk running  into heap corruption.

Other than that don't forget that when you call `malloc()` you get raw memory - no constructor is invoked - and when you call `free()` no destructor is invoked. This can as well lead to undefined behavior and improper functioning of the program.

The bottom line is... never do this.

Answer (score 1):

1) Undefined behaviour but will probably "work" though.  Destructors will get called on the memory being freed that pobably doesn't want to be deconstructed.
2) Undefined behaviour but will probably "work" though.  Destructors will NOT get called.

ie IF it works, and there is no guarantee of that, then it will only, likely, work exactly as required for basic builtin data types.