# new/delete/free store and malloc/free/heap combinations

Tags: c++, memory-management

`new/delete` keywords are use the free store

`malloc/free` keywords are use the heap

i see written somewhere that `new` use `malloc`. how could it be? they are not use in the memory segment?

second, i see written somewhere that we can't use `free` after `new` or use `delete` after `malloc`. but if `new` uses `malloc` why `free` will not work?

and where we use `free` after `new` ect'. this is an error or undefined behavior?

thanks

Comment: it's a simple black box abstraction. `new` might use `malloc`, but you cannot rely on it. also, `malloc` doesn't call the destructor.

Comment: but they use other memory segment? how could they work together?

Comment: be more patient, don't repeat your question.

Comment: @asafapp: Scroll down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `new`/`delete` keywords are use the free store
>   `malloc`/`free` keywords are use the heap
>   i see written somewhere that `new` use `malloc`. how could it be? they are not use in the memory segment?

The "free store" in C++ is a term that describes the place where objects of dynamic storage duration live. The term "the heap" is a colloquialism for *the same thing*. `new` may use `malloc` and that's fine.

However, it does other stuff too, such as invoking constructors and, potentially, instead of `malloc` using some other memory management system (such as a memory pool).

Yes, it is undefined to `free` an object that you allocated with `new`, primarily because `free` does not invoke class destructors. Similarly for `delete`ing something you created with `malloc`: to do so would be to mix two different allocation/construction idioms and, although you can make it work, it would be spectacularly difficult to do so robustly.

> why this memory segment have two names?

Because "the heap" (which is not even a "memory segment") may not be a heap so it's a stupid term. C++ tried to phase it out by introducing the abstraction "free store". Unfortunately, people keep saying "the heap" because of (a) legacy, (b) copy-cat bikeshedding, (c) ignorance of the purpose/meaning/value of abstraction, and (d) poor education/instruction.

Comment: why this memory segment have two names?

Comment: @asafapp: Because "the heap" may not be a heap so it's a stupid term. C++ tried to phase it out by introducing the abstraction "free store". Unfortunately, people keep saying "the heap" because of (a) legacy, (b) copy-cat bikeshedding, (c) ignorance of the purpose/meaning/value of abstraction, and (d) poor education/instruction.

Comment: because the standard likes to keep things abstract, and not tie things to a concrete implementation. and e) because in practice, it's the heap.

Comment: Also, *it's not a memory segment*. It's just an abstract name for free memory, regardless of where it comes from or whether it all comes from the same place.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit. people say that new use free store and malloc use the heap. if they are the same. why to do that complicate

Comment: @asafapp: Because people are silly and the world is big. There is a _lot_ of misinformation out there.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first question: Free store and heap are synonyms.  See for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28programming%29.   So there is no contradiction there.

As for why not to mix new and delete, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3184129/2050788 gives an excellent summary.  Copy pasted for your convenience:

> If you do so you will run into undefined behavior. Never try that. Although new might be implemented through malloc() and delete might be implemented through free() there's no guarantee that they are really implemented that way and also the user can overload new and delete at his discretion. You risk running into heap corruption.
>
> Other than that don't forget that when you call malloc() you get raw memory - no constructor is invoked - and when you call free() no destructor is invoked. This can as well lead to undefined behavior and improper functioning of the program.
>
> The bottom line is... never do this.

Answer (score 1):

In short: *Never* combine these memory management methods. That is, never use `free` on memory allocated via `new` and vice versa.

Now some C++ standard library implementations do in fact implement `operator new` using `malloc`, so it might work in some cases on some platforms, but you mustn't rely on that, as an implementation is neither guaranteed nor required to do so.

Additionally, `free` will not call destructors, and then, C++ classes may provide specialized memory management, which will definitely break if you mix it with `malloc`/`free`.