# Why there is something wrong when invoking ctor in another ctor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Here is a demo code snippet(https://godbolt.org/z/31Tq3r):

```
 #include<iostream>

class Ctx
{
public:
    enum RUN_MOD
    {
        MOD_RT,
        MOD_NRT,
    };

    Ctx(RUN_MOD runType)
    {
        if(runType == MOD_RT)
        {
            Ctx();
        }
    }

    Ctx()
    {
        m_L = malloc(100);
        std::cout << "set m_L=" << m_L << std::endl;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout <<"print() m_L=" << m_L << std::endl;
    }

private:
    void *m_L;

    const char* const ARG_TYPE_NOT_MATCH = "the type of argument is not match";
    const char* const ARG_NUM_INVALID = "the number of arguments is invalid";
    const char* const STACK_OPS_INPUT_ARG_INVALID = "the input argument passed to the stack ops is invalid";
};


int main()
{
    Ctx ctx(Ctx::RUN_MOD::MOD_RT);

    ctx.print();
}
```

Here are outputs when invoking the binary program on Ubuntu:

```
set m_L=0x614c20 
print() m_L=0x400ad0
```

You see the addresses are not the same. I have set `m_L` by invoking `Ctx::Ctx()`(which is called by `Ctx::Ctx(RUN_MOD runType)`) indeed. I am really confused.

Comment: *I am really confused.* --  `if(runType == MOD_RT) { Ctx();}` -- This doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I want to reuse a specific ctor. This code snippet is just for demo.

Comment: The code you posted is what we have to work with, demo or no demo.  That line of code does not "chain on" the next constructor.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++. Use `new`. Or even better, use `std::unique_ptr`. That prevents memory leaks like you have now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Do you mean I should not call another ctor in a specific ctor?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with invoking a constructor within a constructor. It will do exactly what you tell it to do. In your case you tell it to create a new local object and immediately destroy that. (Aldo causing an instant memory leak)

Comment: @John -- C++ is one of the most difficult languages to learn, and to learn it properly requires [peer-reviewed books and other material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  From what I gather, it looks like you're trying to learn by trial and error (or perusing poor websites or material), which is not the way C++ can be properly learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor delegation can only be used from inside a constructor’s [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), NOT inside a constructor’s body.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65377689/65863) shows how to avoid the need to use constructor delegation at all, by creating a common initialization function that multiple constructors can then call as needed.

However, if you did want to use constructor delegation, for whatever reason, then in this case the `Ctx()` constructor should delegate to the `Ctx(RUN_MOD)` constructor, not the other way around as you originally attempted, eg:

```cpp
class Ctx
{
public:
    enum RUN_MOD
    {
        MOD_RT,
        MOD_NRT,
    };

    Ctx(RUN_MOD runType)
    {
        if (runType == MOD_RT)
        {
            m_L = malloc(100);
            std::cout << "set m_L=" << m_L << std::endl;
        }
    }

    Ctx() : Ctx(MOD_RT) // <— here
    {
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "print() m_L=" << m_L << std::endl;
    }

private:
    void *m_L = nullptr;

    const char* const ARG_TYPE_NOT_MATCH = "the type of argument is not match";
    const char* const ARG_NUM_INVALID = "the number of arguments is invalid";
    const char* const STACK_OPS_INPUT_ARG_INVALID = "the input argument passed to the stack ops is invalid";
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a clean solution you could use a function that does, what the default constructor should do. This way you don't need constructor delegation, which afaik can't be applied conditional and you don't have to mess with placement new.

Minimal example:

```
class Ctx
{
private:
    void DefaultInit()
    {
        m_L = malloc(100);
        std::cout << "set m_L=" << m_L << std::endl;
    } 

public:
    Ctx(RUN_MOD runType)
    {
        if(runType == MOD_RT)
        {
            this->DefaultInit();
        }
    }

    Ctx()
    {
       this->DefaultInit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling ctor of any class makes an instance of it, in your posted code it is obvious that allocated **m_l** in **Ctx()** is not belong to the object constructed by **Ctx(RUN_MOD runType)**

try below code

```
void init_m_l()
{
    m_L = malloc(100);
    std::cout << "set m_L=" << m_L << std::endl;
}

Ctx(RUN_MOD runType)
{
    if(runType == MOD_RT)
       init_m_l();
}

Ctx()
{
    init_m_l();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, here is the code snippet(https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/964309f60f62dbd4, it works, but I am still trying to understand it):

```
#include<iostream>

class Ctx
{
public:
    enum RUN_MOD
    {
        MOD_RT,
        MOD_NRT,
    };

    Ctx(RUN_MOD runType)
    {
        if(runType == MOD_RT)
        {
            new (this)Ctx();
        }
    }

    Ctx()
    {
        m_L = malloc(100);
        std::cout << "set m_L=" << m_L << std::endl;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout <<"print() m_L=" << m_L << std::endl;
    }

    ~Ctx()
    {
        free(m_L);
    }

    Ctx(const Ctx&) = delete;  //to avoid double free

private:
    void *m_L;

    const char* const ARG_TYPE_NOT_MATCH = "the type of argument is not match";
    const char* const ARG_NUM_INVALID = "the number of arguments is invalid";
    const char* const STACK_OPS_INPUT_ARG_INVALID = "the input argument passed to the stack ops is invalid";
};


int main()
{
    Ctx ctx(Ctx::RUN_MOD::MOD_RT);

    ctx.print();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution is obfuscated C++.

Comment: So now you have a dilemma -- how do you deallocate that pointer?  Do you use `free`, or do you use `delete`?

Comment: I use `free` to release the allocated memory. See the edited answer.

Comment: *I use free* -- No good.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184118/new-delete-malloc-free)

Answer (score 0):

It's a good answer, but the author deleted it.
I posted it here for more people to study.

his code:

```
if(runType == MOD_RT)
{
    Ctx();
}
```

creates a temporary `Ctx()` object, and -- that's it. Nothing more, nothing less. That temporary just gets destroyed as soon as that line of code is finished executing.

There are other major issues with the class, such as using malloc, the class leaks memory due to not following the rule of 3, not initializing all the members (which I addressed by setting `m_L` to `nullptr`), etc.

Comment: I deleted it since the answer given by @churill is basically a duplicate.  Also, you really shouldn't copy verbatim what was deleted.  Others can see the deleted post.

Comment: I see, I will delete the duplicated part. But I think your answer explain the issues with the code more clearly. Could you please explain the last paragraph in more detail for me?(i.e " the class leaks memory due to not following the rule of 3, not initializing all the members". I can release the allocated memory by `free` later. So I am confused why you say this.)

Comment: `int main() { Ctx x1; Ctx x2 = x1; }` -- Try that, and be highly disappointed in what gets "freed".  You now have a double-free error.  That's what the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) is all about.  Go to the **Managing resources** section of that link.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think I understand what you mean now after I carefully read the aforementioned section. I should add `Ctx(const Ctx&) = delete;` for my case(the memory which `m_L` poins to is used as a memory pool). Am I right? Thank you for your generous help.