# Initializer list - Java

Tags: java, initialization

Recently I came across the following definition when preparing for a Java interview:

**All executable code executes either within an initializer list or a method.**

But from my understanding, Java does not support initializer list as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154654/why-doesnt-java-have-intializer-lists-like-in-c)

Then why does the author gave a definition like above, when Java does not support initializer list?

Comment: Book: Oracle Certified Associate.
Author: M. Reese Richard.

Comment: Sorry for off-topic. Is it a good book otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for that Author, but my understanding is, he/she means Static Initialization Blocks (or) instance blocks. Refer [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for more information on these blocks.

Answer (score 0):

What is should be read as is "**Executable code should be within initializer block (static or non static), constructor or a method**"

So if `System.out.println("executable statement")` is our executable statement, then

```
public class SomeClass{

static{
    System.out.println("executable statement");    
}

{

System.out.println("executable statement");
}

public SomeClass(){

System.out.println("executable statement");
}

public void someMethod(){

System.out.println("executable statement");

}

}
```

This is valid code while

```
public class SomeClass{
   System.out.println("executable statement");

}
```

gives compiler error